# How to do cross rows operation in SAS ?

Tags: sas, levenshtein-distance

I have an email list in SAS dataset. I want to identify similar email address from the list. I am trying to implement COMPGED function across all the rows for email variable. I need to sort the list based on similar distance so that similar email address become neighbours. Can anybody help on this please ?

Comment: What's your code at the moment? What's wrong with the result?

Comment: For this type of linkage you can try the options here, the solution from @friedegg is good in terms of compged and the reference to the the-link-king.com is a good option as well. https://communities.sas.com/t5/SAS-Procedures/Name-matching/m-p/82780/highlight/true#M23757

Answer (score 0):

Do a self join in `proc sql`, using the result of `compged` as criteria for join condition :

Example :

```
proc sql ;
  create table similar_emails as
  select a.Email as EmailA, b.Email as EmailB
  from email_list a
       left join
       email_list b on compged(a.Email,b.Email) <= 200 
  order by a.Email ;
quit ;
```

Comment: But I have only one email list. Suppose I have n no. Of email ids. I have to compare 1st email id with rest (n-1) email ids, 2nd email id with rest (n-1) ids.

Comment: Use a cross join instead of left join, sort on the score and add it the select statement as well.

Comment: My example is based on a single list of emails. If you wish to exclude an email from matching to itself, give each row an ID in a preceding datastep, and add `and a.ID ^= b.ID` to the join condition.

Comment: Or you can just delete any observation where emailA=emailB